# Entity Framework: Populating a many-to-many relationship with existing data (seed)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, dbcontext, seeding

In my Code-First database i have a many-to-many relationship between the object "Question" and the object "Section", which is noted as follows:
In Section:

```
public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
```

In Question:

```
public List<Section> Sections { get; set; }
```

This does create a link table between the two, called QuestionSections.
However, when I try to run my seed method, the link table does not get populated.

The relevant part of the code of the seed method is as follows:

```
var Sections = new List<Section>
{
    new Section
    {
        InternalSectionId = 1,
        Name = "Global information",
        SurveyId = context.Surveys.First(s => s.Title == "Test Survey").Id
    },
    new Section
    {
        InternalSectionId = 2,
        Name = "More specific",
        SurveyId = context.Surveys.First(s => s.Title == "Test Survey").Id
    },
    new Section
    {
        InternalSectionId = 3,
        Name = "TestingSection",
        SurveyId = context.Surveys.First(s => s.Title == "Test Survey").Id
    }
};
Sections.ForEach(x => context.Sections.AddOrUpdate(ss => ss.Name, x));
context.SaveChanges();

List<Section> section1 = context.Sections.Where(sect => sect.InternalSectionId == 1 && sect.SurveyId == 1)
    .ToList();
List<Section> section2 = context.Sections.Where(sect => sect.InternalSectionId == 2 && sect.SurveyId == 1)
    .ToList();
List<Section> section3 = context.Sections.Where(sect => sect.InternalSectionId == 3 && sect.SurveyId == 1)
    .ToList();

var questions = new List<Question>
            {
                new Question
                {
                    Sections = section1,
                    Title = "What is 1+1?",
                    QuestionOrderId = 1,
                    AnswerRequired = true,
                    InputTypeId = context.InputTypes.First(ip => ip.VisibleName.Equals("Dropdownbox")).Id,
                    StorageType = (int)Constants.Constants.StorageTypes.BoolType
                },
                new Question
                {
                    Sections = section2,
                    Title = "What is 2/1?",
                    QuestionOrderId = 1,
                    AnswerRequired = true,
                    InputTypeId = context.InputTypes.First(ip => ip.VisibleName.Equals("Text")).Id,
                    StorageType = (int)Constants.Constants.StorageTypes.IntType
                    }
                }
            }
questions.ForEach(x => context.Questions.AddOrUpdate(q => q.Title, x));
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
context.SaveChanges();
```

The questions get created, the sections get created, but the link table is not populated.
I have checked if the objects section1, section2, and section3 are initiated and populated, and they are.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to write the similar code to Link table also.
`questions.ForEach(x => context.Questions.AddOrUpdate(q => q.Title, x));`

Comment: @viveknuna
I found this on a different question: 
    var customerGroups = 
context.CustomerGroups.Where(...).ToList(); // get your 
    CustomerGroup object(s) here, and ensure it's enumerated with ToList()
    entity.CustomerGroups = customerGroups;
    context.Customers.Add(entity);
    context.SaveChanges();

This says you can just insert the first object into the second object, is this wrong?

Comment: I didn't understand you? Did my comment help you?

Comment: in other words, is it best practice to manually populate the link table? Doesn't that go against the essence of ef-codefirst?

Comment: Yes, You have to, because there can be multiple scenarios where you don't want to insert records to link table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the similar code to Link table also. `questions.ForEach(x => context.Questions.AddOrUpdate(q => q.Title, x));` because DBContext has no idea of this link table when you are calling `context.SaveChanges();`.